# I can't import turtle module into python 2.7.10 due to a "width error not defined"

Tags: python, module, width, turtle-graphics

So I copy paste this code from my online course into my python 2.7.10 and run it. It says that width is not defined. I tried to look for questions adressing this but couldn't find and also Im starting to learn coding so I don't know how to import the turtle module without giving me an error.

```
from turtle import *    # loads the turtle library...
width(5)        # make the turtle pen 5 pixels wide
shape('turtle') # use a turtle shape!
forward(100)    # turtle goes forward 100 steps
right(90)       # turtle turns right 90 degrees
up()            # turtle lifts its pen up off of the paper
forward(100)    # turtle goes forward 100 steps
down()          # turtle puts its pen down on the paper
color("red")    # turtle uses red pen
circle(100)     # turtle draws circle of radius 100 
color("blue")   # turtle changes to blue pen
forward(50)     # turtle moves forward 50 steps

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    from turtle import *    # loads the turtle library...
  File "turtle.py", line 2, in <module>
    width(5)        # make the turtle pen 5 pixels wide
NameError: name 'width' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have this or another file named `turtle.py` in the same folder. You should rename the file to something else.

Comment: That's my vote too. After de-mangling this code, it works fine for me.